# How to get height of label inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Say I have a simple `tableViewCell` with only one view(`UILabel`) and `tableView` has 10 rows and text for `label` at different positions is varying from 1 to 3 lines , now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath{
  [MyCell* cell = _tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
  cell.label.text = [stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

now i want to add `cornerRadius` to that `label` which is proportional to height of that label (say corner radius is half of label height)

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height/2;
```

**now my question is where do i get to set this corner radius for label ??**

1. I tried to set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but i was getting wrong height value
2. I tried to override `layoutForSubViews`  in MyCell class like this.

   ```
   -(void)layoutSubviews{
     [super layoutSubviews];
      self.label.layer.cornerRadius = self.label.frame.size.height/2;
   }
   ```

   but still i was getting wrong height value
3. I tried to do this at `-willDisplayCell` callback from tableView and still wrong height

only thing that seems to work is to override `drawRect` of the cell and assign `cornerRadius`. Is this the only way to do this ?

Comment: try cell.label.cornerRadius = cell.label.frame.size.height/2;

Comment: @DSDharma where should i do this ? in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes add above code in that method

Comment: just add label.bounds.size.hight

Comment: cell.label.text = [stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; after this line just add cell.lable.cornerradius = cell.lable.bounds.size.hight / 2

Comment: @DSDharma sorry but did you read full description? As I said i tried it but label's height is coming wrong, it us not giving me the correct height of the label which i just set

Comment: @kr15hna i think you did not read my complete comment so you say like that

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya sorry i was replying to DS Dharma , trying what you said

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya no both frame.size.height and bounds.size.height have same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can try using `[cell.label sizeToFit];` and access frame after this, in cellForRowAtIndex path for example.

But size to fit can lead to a layout bug.

Also, @DSDharma comment should be useful, but you need to override `- (void) layoutSubviews` right in UITableViewCell subclass. That should work.

Comment: this is correct answer to question, but if i may ask another question can you please tell me how to get the updated height if my cell has multiple label, constraints, some other views ? do i have to do sizeToFit for all those views and add them accordingly?

Comment: wait so sizeToFit is not the right way to do it? I did override layoutSubviews in UITableViewCell subclass only(sorry of for not mentioning that clearly in question) still getting wrong height value

Comment: @kr15hna, yes, sizeToFit may work but it isnt best way to do so. Btw, do you need to get total cell height or you need to get correct labels frames?

Comment: total cell height

Comment: Well, total cell height probably can be accessed this way: 
firstly call sizeToFit or use boundingRectWithSize... (see next answer here), then use this formula: label1.frame.size.origin.y + label1.frame.size.height + label2.frame.origin.y + label2.frame.size.height + ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right height of UITableViewCell label inside sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

Use below code

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary *currentObject = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *datum = [currentObject valueForKey:@"yourKeyName"];

    CGSize size = [datum boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontFamily" size:16]} context:nil].size;

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get Label height.

```
- (CGFloat)getLabelHeight:(UILabel*)label
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, 999);
    CGSize size;
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
    CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                                  context:context].size;
    size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
    return size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate size `sizeWithFont constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` use this method.

**Example:**

```
// FLT_MAX here simply means no constraint in height
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

//update label with new Height
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

And set `CornerRadius` with `newFrame` value